# Update Texture2D pixels from C++

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, pinvoke

In the project, I'm using Unity3D's C# scripts and C++ via DllImports. My goal is that the game scene has 2 cubes `(Cube & Cube2)` which one texture of cube show the live video through my laptop camera and Unity's `webCamTexture.Play()` and the other one texture of cube show the processed video by external C++ function `ProcessImage()`.

**Code Context:**

In c++, I define that

```
struct Color32
{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char a;
};
```

and the function is

```
extern "C"
{
    Color32* ProcessImage(Color32* raw, int width, int height);
}
...

Color32* ProcessImage(Color32* raw, int width, int height)
{
    for(int i=0; i<width*height ;i++)
    {
       raw[i].r = raw[i].r-2;
       raw[i].g = raw[i].g-2;
       raw[i].b = raw[i].b-2;
       raw[i].a = raw[i].a-2;
    }
    return raw;
}
```

C#:

Declare and importing

```
public GameObject cube; 
public GameObject cube2;
private Texture2D tx2D;
private WebCamTexture webCamTexture;

[DllImport("test22")]   /*the name of Plugin is test22*/
private static extern Color32[] ProcessImage(Color32[] rawImg, 
                                                 int width, int height);
```

Get camera situation and set cube1, cube2 Texture

```
void Start()
{
    WebCamDevice[] wcd = WebCamTexture.devices;

    if(wcd.Length==0)
    {
        print("Cannot find a camera");
        Application.Quit();
    }
    else
    {
        webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture(wcd[0].name);
        cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = webCamTexture;

        tx2D = new Texture2D(webCamTexture.width, webCamTexture.height);
        cube2.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tx2D;

        webCamTexture.Play();
    }
}
```

Send data to external C++ function by `DllImports` and receive processed data using `Color32[] a`. Finally, I'm using Unity's `SetPixels32` to setup `tx2D`(Cube2) texture:

```
void Update()
{
    Color32[] rawImg = webCamTexture.GetPixels32();
    System.Array.Reverse(rawImg);

    Debug.Log("Test1");
    Color32[] a = ProcessImage(rawImg, webCamTexture.width, webCamTexture.height);
    Debug.Log("Test2");

    tx2D.SetPixels32(a);
    tx2D.Apply();
}
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

The result is just the texture of cube 1 show the live video and fail to show processed data using the texture of cube 2.

Error:

> SetPixels32 called with invalid number of pixels in the array
>   UnityEngine.Texture2D:SetPixels32(Color32[]) Webcam:Update() (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Webcam.cs:45)

I don't understand that why the invalid number of pixels in the array when I input array a to SetPixels32

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**(10 Oct. 2018)

Thanks to @Programmer, now it can work by pin memory.

[image]

Btw, I find some little [problem](https://answers.unity.com/questions/773464/webcamtexture-correct-resolution-and-ratio.html#answer-1148424) which is about Unity Engine. When the Unity Camera run between 0 to 1 second, `webCamTexture.width` or `webCamTexture.height` always return `16x16` size even requested bigger image such as 1280x720 and then it will return correct size after 1 second. [(Possibly several frames)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9nFf.png) So, I reference this [post](http://answers.unity.com/answers/396143/view.html) and delay 2 seconds to run `Process()` in `Update()` function and reset the Texture2D size in `Process()` function. It will work fine:

```
delaytime = 0;
void Update()
{
    delaytime = delaytime + Time.deltaTime;
    Debug.Log(webCamTexture.width);
    Debug.Log(webCamTexture.height);

    if (delaytime >= 2f)
        Process();
}
unsafe void Process()
{
    ...

    if ((Test.width != webCamTexture.width) || Test.height != webCamTexture.height)
    {
       Test = new Texture2D(webCamTexture.width, webCamTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, false);
       cube2.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = Test;
       Debug.Log("Fixed Texture dimension");
    }
    ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the codes where you define and initialize Texture2D tx2D variable?

Comment: Texture2D tx2D initialize *new Texture2D(webCamTexture.width, webCamTexture.height)*    <br/>The codes are already  upload and you can watch on this website [link: https://codeshare.io/G6gkjz]

Comment: im having issues with the same thing, could you please share what you did to make it work? im unable to move the cv::Mat array of the processed image from c++ to C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# doesn't return understand the `Color32` object you returned from C++. This would have worked if you made the return type to be `unsigned char*` then use `Marshal.Copy` on the C# side to copy the returned data into byte array then use [`Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html) to load the array into your `Texture2D`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047164/3785314) is an example that returns byte array from C#.

---

I wouldn't suggest you return data as that's costly. Fill the array you are passing to the function then simply re-assign that array to your `Texture2D`.

**C++:**

```
extern "C"
{
    void ProcessImage(unsigned char* raw, int width, int height);
}
...

void ProcessImage(unsigned char* raw, int width, int height)
{
    for(int y=0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x < width; x++)
        {
            unsigned char* pixel = raw + (y * width * 4 + x * 4);
            pixel[0] = pixel[0]-(unsigned char)2; //R
            pixel[1] = pixel[1]-(unsigned char)2; //G
            pixel[2] = pixel[2]-(unsigned char)2; //B
            pixel[3] = pixel[3]-(unsigned char)2; //Alpha
        }
    }
}
```

**C#:**

```
[DllImport("test22")]
private static extern void ProcessImage(IntPtr texData, int width, int height);

unsafe void ProcessImage(Texture2D texData)
{
    Color32[] texDataColor = texData.GetPixels32();
    System.Array.Reverse(texDataColor);

    //Pin Memory
    fixed (Color32* p = texDataColor)
    {
        ProcessImage((IntPtr)p, texData.width, texData.height);
    }
    //Update the Texture2D with array updated in C++
    texData.SetPixels32(texDataColor);
    texData.Apply();
}
```

To use:

```
public Texture2D tex;

void Update()
{
    ProcessImage(tex);
}
```

If you don't want to use the `unsafe` and `fixed` keywords, you can also use `GCHandle.Alloc` to pin the array before sending it to the C++ side with `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49486419/3785314) post for how to do that.

---

If you are getting the following exception:

> SetPixels32 called with invalid number of pixels in the array
>   UnityEngine.Texture2D:SetPixels32(Color32[]) Webcam:Update() (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Webcam.cs:45)

This means that the `Texture2D` you're calling `SetPixels32` on has different size or texture dimension with the `WebCamTexture` texture. To fix this, before calling `SetPixels32`, check if the texture dimension changed then resize your target texture to match with the `WebCamTexture`.

Replace

```
tx2D.SetPixels32(rawImg);
tx2D.Apply();
```

with

```
//Fix texture dimension if it doesn't match with the web cam texture size
if ((tx2D.width != webCamTexture.width) || tx2D.height != webCamTexture.height)
{
    tx2D = new Texture2D(webCamTexture.width, webCamTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
    Debug.Log("Fixed Texture dimension");
}

tx2D.SetPixels32(rawImg);
tx2D.Apply();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunate, I reference your suggestion, thought and modify the codes. It also appears the same error message. If you want to watch the detail of the code, I am already uploaded to this website: https://codeshare.io/G6gkjz

Comment: Made an edit to the answer to address that error. Check it out. Let me know if there is still a problem.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is fixed by clicking on the green check-mark on my answer.

Comment: Thanks to @Programmer, now it can work by pin memory. But, I have a little problem is that if I process the image using OpenCV Library. For more detail, it is in my post "Update" part.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how it works here. This post is not about OpenCV and the original post wass about updating Texture2D pixels from C++. I think the problem is now solved. When you ask a question and it's solved but then you want to do different stuff and run into issues, you accept the current answer then create new question. You should create new question with your OpenCV post. Make sure to also tag OpenCV in the new question. You may want to remove the OpenCV edit you made into this question.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!! :)